# Android - Google map clustering bug with markers not being reclustered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Edit: Show what the `mapManager.filter()` method does.

I have an Android app with ~20k markers being draw on the map and with filters option so the markers are being drawn and remove a lot.
I'm currently using [this clustering library](https://github.com/sharewire/google-maps-clustering) because it's way more efficient for displaying a large amount of markers than the classic google map library. But it's not supported and hasn't been updated since 3 years and i haven't found any alternatives.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UggePCgYigw&ab_channel=Tom.A) is a video of the bug.

Here is my code that is call when i click on an filtering option in my app:

```
 private void filter(){
    
    //currentMapManager contain all the filters option and also the array list
    //of the unfiltered markers (~20,000 markers)
    //it's filter method retrieve the current filtering option enable (marker type, and other specs)
    //And return markers from the full arraylist that match those filters options.

    ArrayList<MarkerModel> filteredList = currentMapManager.filter(currentMapManager.getAllMarkers());

    if (clusterManager != null) {
        clusterManager.setItems(new ArrayList<>());
        clusterManager.onCameraIdle();
        clusterManager.setItems(filteredList);
        clusterManager.onCameraIdle();
    }
```

Here the `mapManager.filter()` method.

```
public ArrayList<MarkerModel> filter(List<MarkerModel> currentMarkers) {
    ArrayList<Object> filtersArray = filters.getFilters();
    /* filtersArray is an array like this : 
    * ['type', ['typeFilter1', 'typeFilter2'], 
    * 'date', dateTimestamp, 
    * 'withPictures', true, 
    * ....] 
    */
    return filter(currentMarkers, filtersArray);
}

private ArrayList<MarkerModel> filter(List<MarkerModel> currentMarkers, 
                                      ArrayList<Object> fieldsAndValues) {
  
    if (fieldsAndValues.size() % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing value in call to filterList().  
        There must be an even number of arguments that alternate between 
        field names and values");
    } else {
        //Here the arraylist that we are returning
        ArrayList<MarkerModel> filteredMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Object> argumentList = new ArrayList();
        Collections.addAll(argumentList, fieldsAndValues);

        if (!currentMarkers.isEmpty()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < currentMarkers.size(); j++) {
                MarkerModel marker = currentMarkers.get(j);
                boolean isInFilter = true;
                //Check fieldsAndValue filters...
                //If isInFilter stay to true we 
                
                filteredMarkers.add(marker);
            }
        }
        return filteredMarkers;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that the cluster library is not supposed to have so much redrawn and it broke at some point from reading and working on 20k items arraylist.
I have look through all the forks branch of this library and look/try to understand the library source code but hasn't find any solution at my problem...

If you need other part of my source code to understand more tell me i will add it.

Thanks a lot if you can help me i have been struggling a lot with this issue...

Comment: One thing I notice in the library implementation of `setItems` is it attempts to cancel any active `mQuadTreeTask ` but does not wait for the `onCancelled` (probably because it makes the implemenation more complicated).  However in rapid zoom ins/outs this could reveal an issue since each outstanding task operates on the same, one quadTree.  Read more about the `cancel` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean).

Comment: With that said, it looks as though it uses a single-threaded executor which means the above would not apply since only one task could ever be running - still a wrong implementation though - especially since you don't know when `setItems` is actually complete (from client perspective) - e.g. what if you change `filteredList` - does `currentMapManager.filter` return a clone or a new list (note the initialization of `filteredList` in the posted code above does nothing) since you are just overwriting.

Comment: Just bear in mind in your code: that when you call `setItems` and it returns _it's not actually done_ due to the asynctask implementation - it really should provide a "complete callback."

Comment: Thanks Andy ! I'm going to look to implement this `onComplete` with a `listener` and will tell you if it resolve the issue or not. 
For the initialization of `filteredList` it's because i have more code with some if/else for my global filtering options (and not related to the `currentMapManager`) but i have removed many lines for simplifying here.
`currentMapManager.filter` return a new list i have edit my question to show a little bit what it does (simplified again)

Comment: It may prove difficult to introduce a callback because the `mQuadTreeTask` on completion spawns a second task ( `ClusterTask` ) to initiate the clustering update. Note also that `onCameraIdle` initiates a `ClusterTask` which means your `setItems` initiates a clustering followed immediately by a second clustering with `onCameraIdle`.  I'd recommend setting up a simple map project with 100k markers and various "filtered" cases using your code and observe results - I may do this myself and post results.  Also add a succinct explanation for video as to what you consider incorrect - for clarity.

Comment: After adding logs and debug in the library and tearing myself apart for the past 3 days (one after posting on stackOverflow). I have noticed strange animation on my markers. 
And after further invistigation i found out it was because in my database i have 19.5k markers and after filtering the one without unique lat lng (duplication but also the one with less than 8 digit) i have only 18,5k markers.... 
And no more problems of clusterisation. So i will try to remove my callbacks (that i have added after your suggestion) and see if it's still work !